# Spring security with Hibernate and Annotations and basic HTTP authentication

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

After studying many examples, I can't find any example that shows how create Spring Security configurations, while Roles are listed in annotations and Hibernate is used for authentication.

My files:

mvc-dispather-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
    <import resource="classpath:hibernate-beans.xml" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.salespredict"/>

</beans>
```

spring-security.xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<http>
     <http-basic/>
</http>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="authenticationService" />
</authentication-manager>

<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

</beans:beans>
```

Service:

@Service
public class AuthenticationService implements UserDetailsService {

```
@Autowired
private IUserRepository userRepository;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findOne(username);
    Set<Role> roles = user.getRoles();
    Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
    for(Role role:roles) {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole().name()));
    }
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
            user.getUsername(),
            user.getPassword(),
            authorities);
}
```

}

Controller:

```
@Controller
@Secured({RoleNames.ADMIN, RoleNames.SALES_PREDICT_ADMIN})
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class Admin extends WebServiceBase {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
    public
    @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity registerNewUsers(InputStream data) throws Exception {
        // deserialize from JSON
        Users users = _mapper.readValue(data, Users.class);
        PutUsers msg = new PutUsers(users.getUsers());
        postMessage(msg, DefaultResponse.class);
        return ok();
     }
    ...
    }
```

If I change `<http>` to

```
 <http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <http-basic />
</http>
```

Then my authentication service is called, but it just checks whether a user provides a password, it does not check roles. If I remove it, authentication servic is not called at all.

What should I write in `<intercept-url pattern="/**" access= ... >` to make it checking roles from @Secured annotation?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear but have you tried `access="ROLE_someRole"`?

Comment: No, I put roles in @Secured annotations in controller.

Comment: So you are saying `@Secured` annotation isn't working?

Comment: Yes, I can do http authentication, but method level using @Secured annotation is not working

Comment: Maybe spring cannot create proxy of you class. Try setting `proxy-target-class` in `global-method-security`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your

```
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
```

declaration to `mvc-dispather-servlet.xml` because your `Admin` controller is picked up by `mvc-dispather-servlet.xml` and not by `spring-security.xml`. See corresponding [FAQ entry](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq.html#faq-method-security-in-web-context).

Comment: And CGLib is in your classpath? And there is no runtime exception during sturtup?

Comment: No exceptions, cglin in path