# How to create a authentication popup like this in a browser?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

[Popup in an application to authenticate the user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtNDe.png)

I need to develop an application and authenticate users who login to the application. I need to trigger a popup like this (image attached) and configure to xxx server for validation. 
I need to develop the application in JSP,Spring MVC with hibernate.

Right now I'm running the application in localhost.

Comment: This looks like Basic Authentication. It can be enabled in the web.xml configuration file. The dialog will be presented by the browser so its look and feel is controlled by the client side.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like Basic Authentication. It can be enabled in the web.xml configuration file. The dialog will be presented by the browser so its look and feel is controlled by the client side.

For Spring, check if this helps:

[Spring security with Hibernate and Annotations and basic HTTP authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120968/spring-security-with-hibernate-and-annotations-and-basic-http-authentication)